# how to skip use of extra variable for python operation?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working on a python code I have used temp variable because If there is any content present, that will be appended to temp variable and then it will be appended to header.
and if there is no content then temp variable will be appended.

so, it will restrict to append '' values  to the list.

I am looking for any other finer method to get the same result but not using temp variable.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
    temp = ''
    header = []
    for ind,content in enumerate(data):   # enumerating for index & content in data
        if content and ind != 0:
            temp = content
            header.append(content)
        else:
            header.append(temp)
```

input :

```
['column1', '', '', '', 'column2', '', '']
```

expected output :

```
['column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column2', 'column2', 'column2']
```

Comment: Could you give some examples of input and output?

Comment: updated the question with expected output for input

Comment: may the first entry of the input list equal `''` ?

Comment: I think the problem is naming `temp` variable as `temp`. It confused me for half of a minute what the program supposes to do. Renaming it to something like "previous_header" might help solving your problem in the first place. Although I am speaking from an observer point of view, naming variable is really important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
>>> data=['column1', '', '', '', 'column2', '', '']
>>> header=data[:]
>>> for i in range(1,len(header)):
    if not header[i]:
        header[i]=header[i-1]


>>> header
['column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column2', 'column2', 'column2']
>>>
```

Note** I have updated the answer to as not to update the original list.

Comment: The above modifies the list `data`.  If that's not allowed, make a copy first: `header = list(data)`.  Then you also need to handle the zero case: if data[0] is empty, what should it become?  The original code leaves the output list element `header[0]` empty.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i, x in enumerate(data[1:], 1):
    if not x:
        data[i] = data[i-1]

# or
for i, x in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if not x:
        data[i+1] = data[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another version of the temp version

Code:

```
REPEAT = object()
def repeated(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        R = last if (x is REPEAT) else x
        yield R
        last = R
```

Demo:

```
>>> input = ['column1', REPEAT, REPEAT, REPEAT, 'column2', REPEAT, REPEAT]
>>> list( repeated(input) )
['column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column2', 'column2', 'column2']
```

Comment: +1 for the nice trick. For a moment I thought you were writing something in PASCAL.... I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flexibility, you could just do:

```
>>> ['column1']*4 + ['column2']*3
['column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column1', 'column2', 'column2', 'column2']
```